# using ThreadSafeReference can only get dynamic value

Tags: ios, multithreading, realm

I have a `Store`, `Area` table, After called api get the `Store` `Area` data, then will create `Store` , `Area` table;

Goal: For render ui, i need `Store` with `areaName`. fetch stores from db and then compose to stores with `areaName`, then compose to a 2d array based on `areaName` in background thread. then pass the 2d array to render ui in main thread

Implementation:

In the background thread read Store, using areaCode get Area, then get areaName, then `store.areaName = area.areaName` get the composed Store, and using `ThreadSafeReference` to get the reference of store

In the main thread using `realm.resolve` to get the store in main thread, but can only get the `store.address` value, can not get the `store.areaName`

```
class Store: Object {
    dynamic var storeCode: String = ""

    dynamic var areaCode: String = ""

    dynamic var address: String = ""
    dynamic var phone: String = ""

    var areaName: String = ""
    var userId: Int = 0
}


class Area: Object {
    dynamic var areaCode: String = ""
    dynamic var areaName: String = ""
}

//// in background thread//////
let realmInBack = try! Realm()
let stores = getStore(by userId: Int) // here get a list of stores from db
stores.forEach{ (store) in
    let area = getArea(by areaCode: String) // get area
    let areaName = area.areaName // get the areaName from area
    store.areaName = areaName // assign areaName to store
    let storeRef = ThreadSafeReference(to: store) // get the storeRef
}
//// in main thread /////
let realm = try! Realm()
let storeInMain = realm.resolve(storeRef)
// then use storeInMain to render ui
```

Could please list the ways to pass realm object through threads?
I currently know the following ways:
1. ThreadSafeReference(failed in my case)
2. transform the realm object to normal class by myself

Comment: Please show the code you are actually using to access the objects from different threads. In its current form your question is quite generic, making it hard to give you a specific answer. Moreover, please conform to the Swift naming convention, which is lower-camelCase for variable names (such as `storeCode` instead of `store_code`).

Comment: thanks for your comment, i've re-edit the question. and in my case i get a realmObject in the background thread, then need to pass the realmObject to main thread to render ui. how could i make it? could you please help to list the ways to make it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this simple case, you don't actually need to use a `ThreadSafeReference` object. You should just save a property of your object to a variable you can use to identify that specific object (preferably its `primaryKey` if you are using `primaryKey`s), then retrieve the object using its primary key from Realm on the main thread.

```
var storeCodeRef = "" //make sure this variable is accessible in the scope of where your code on the main thread is called from as well

let realmInBack = try! Realm()
let stores = getStore(by userId: Int) // here get a list of stores from db
stores.forEach{ (store) in
    let area = getArea(by areaCode: String) // get area
    let areaName = area.areaName // get the areaName from area
    store.areaName = areaName // assign areaName to store
    //save the unique identifier for the store
    storeCodeRef = store.storeCode
}

//// in main thread /////
let realm = try! Realm()
let store = realm.object(ofType: Store.self).filter("storeCode == %@",storeCodeRef).first //assuming storeCodes are unique
```

If you are using a primary key, you can use

```
let store = realm.object(ofType: Store.self, forPrimaryKey: storeCodeRef)
```

Since you declare a new reference to your Realm instance on the main thread and access the `Store` object from that reference, you won't receive any errors.

Update based on comments:

Your `Class` model is flawed. All properties that you want to persist in Realm need to be declared using the `dynamic` keyword, otherwise they cannot be dynamically dispatched to the Obj-C runtime, which Realm uses.

```
class Store: Object {
    dynamic var storeCode: String = ""
    dynamic var areaCode: String = ""
    dynamic var address: String = ""
    dynamic var phone: String = ""
    dynamic var areaName: String = ""
    dynamic var userId: Int = 0
}
```

Second of all, why do you store `ThreadSafeReference`s to individual stores if you want to modify the actual Store objects, you can do that in a write transaction and store a `ThreadSafeReference` to the `Results` instance, so you only need to resolve a single reference and not one for each individual Store.

Below code has been tested and is working in a Realm playground.

```
class Store: Object {
    dynamic var storeCode: String = ""
    dynamic var address: String = ""
    dynamic var phone: String = ""
    dynamic var userId: Int = 0
    dynamic var areaCode: String = ""
    dynamic var areaName: String = ""
}


class Area: Object {
    dynamic var areaCode: String = ""
    dynamic var areaName: String = ""
}

try! realm.write {
    realm.add([Store(value: ["userId":1,"storeCode":"1"]),Store(value: ["userId":1,"storeCode":"2"]),Store(value: ["userId":2,"storeCode":"1"])])
}

print(realm.objects(Store.self))

//// in some thread//////
var storesRef: ThreadSafeReference<Results<Store>>?
DispatchQueue(label: "background").sync {
    autoreleasepool{
        let realmInBack = try! Realm(configuration: Realm.Configuration(inMemoryIdentifier: "TemporaryRealm"))
        let stores = realmInBack.objects(Store.self).filter("userId == 1")
        print("Stores for user 1:",stores)
        try! realmInBack.write {
            let area = Area(value: ["areaCode":"a","areaName":"AreaA"])
            realmInBack.add(area)
            stores.forEach{ (store) in
                store.areaCode = area.areaCode
            }
        }
        print("Modified stores:",stores)
        storesRef = ThreadSafeReference(to: stores)
    }
}
//// in main thread /////
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let mainRealm = try! Realm(configuration: Realm.Configuration(inMemoryIdentifier: "TemporaryRealm"))
    guard let storesRef = storesRef, let storeInMain = mainRealm.resolve(storesRef) else {
        print("Couldn't resolve stores reference"); return
    }
    print("Stores from ThreadSafeReference:",storeInMain)
}
```

Comment: Great thanks for your answer. In actual case, i still have the problems: 1. the Store table do not have a unique key(it is queried by 'storeCode', 'channelCode','startDate','endDate') 2. In the background thread i wanna compose Store with additional data, then compose to a 2d array based on areaName. then pass the 2d array to main thread. In your answer, i have to refetch the stores again, and then composed to 2d array in main thread

Comment: @苏文梁 check my updated answer, included working code using ` ThreadSafeReference`.

Comment: Thanks for you work and that really helps. I still have a question wanna to confirm: If using ThreadSafeReference pass object through thread, only dynamic property could be passed, ignored property can not be passed?  If so, i will declare areaName as dynamic property. here i declare areaName as ignored property, cause when call api get the store info is without areaName key

Comment: Yes, since you are retrieving persisted values from `Realm`, ignored properties will be deleted. Btw, declaring ignored properties should not be done by declaring them without the `dynamic` keyword. You need to add them to the `ignoredProperties` function to make them proper ignored properties.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Here i still have a problem wanna ask you. I have 2 tables:  ```Router```, ```Store```. Firstly i will query ```Router```table, get ```Result<Router>``` then forEach to get ```Result<Store>```,like ```Result<Router>.forEach({ Result<Store>  })```,  my final goal is to get ```Result<Store>``` to using ```ThreadSafeReference```, cause for using ```ThreadSafeReference```, the body should be ```Object```, ```Result``` but here i cannot using appending for ```Result```, and could i using ```Array``` then convert to ```Result```?

Comment: No, you cannot convert an Array to Result. However, I would suggest asking a new question for this new problem, since there was no mention of `Router` in your current question so far.

Comment: Thanks, have posted another question. Here still have one thing struggling with. From the model design perspective, the property ```areaName``` should not persist in ```Store``` table, it is actually ```Area``` table's property. But here also have to pass composed ```Store``` through thread, and need persist ```areaName``` in ```Store```. So in this case, the best solution would be persist ```areaName``` in ```Store```? @Dávid Pásztor

Comment: The best solution would actually be to persist the `Area` only and have a one-to-one relationship in your `Store` model to `Area`.

Comment: One more question, what if i wanna do some data handling in the background thread, like transfrom the ```Result``` to a 2d array. i cannot make it, cause for using ```ThreadSafeReference```  i have to pass ```Result``` through threads,  so have to do the transformation in the main thread, right?

Comment: If you want to persist the changes you make to your data, then yes, you can't transform the `Results` to an Array. If you don't need to persist the changes, you can just make a copy of the objects of `Results` and then you can safely pass the non-persisted copies between threads even in an Array.

Comment: copy objects like this?(add a toNormal function to trans to normal class) : ```class Store: Object {
    dynamic var storeCode: String = ""
    dynamic var areaName: String = ""
    override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
        return ["area_name"]
    }
    func toNormal() -> StoreView {
        let storeView = StoreView()
        storeView.storeCode = self.storeCode
        storeView.areaName = self.areaName
        return storeView
    }
}
class StoreView: NSObject {
    var storeCode: String = ""
    var areaName: String = ""
}```

Comment: No, you don't need to create a new class for that. Non-persisted Realm objects behave just like normal objects. So you can just do `let storeCopy = Store(value: otherStore)`, where `otherStore` is a `Store` instance that you want to copy.