# Conforming [T] array with Realm ThreadConformed

Tags: swift, realm

I want to know how can I achieve a ThreadSafety in array of type `Results<[T]>?`

`[T] does not conform ThreadConfined` is the error

```
anotherdispatchqu.async{
    for object in objects {
        realm.write{
            realm.add(object)
            t = threadsafereference(to:object)
            all.append(t)
        }
    }
    
    Dispacthqueue.main.async{
        let result = realm?.resolve(t) // error... [T] not confined
        completion(result)
    }
}
```

Comment: I would advise you to show us the code you are struggling with. What is type `T`? Also, `Results` don't support arrays.

Comment: Custom Database Object like any realm object

Comment: Results are not arrays and while they have as similar functionality the underlying behavior is different. I am a little confused by the code though; it iterates over objects, creating thread safe ref to each and for each iteration, replaces t and then afterwards resolves the last value of t? So you are only interested in the last value? Perhaps a better option writing all the values and then create a thread safe reference to a result, where you could access all of the objects. Like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46067290/using-threadsafereference-can-only-get-dynamic-value)